# What does `t(sites)` means for presto query?

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, lateral-join

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html) is snippet from aws site:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT ARRAY[
    CAST(
      ROW('aws.amazon.com', ROW(true)) AS ROW(hostname VARCHAR, flaggedActivity ROW(isNew BOOLEAN))
    ),
    CAST(
      ROW('news.cnn.com', ROW(false)) AS ROW(hostname VARCHAR, flaggedActivity ROW(isNew BOOLEAN))
    ),
    CAST(
      ROW('netflix.com', ROW(false)) AS ROW(hostname VARCHAR, flaggedActivity ROW(isNew BOOLEAN))
    )
  ] as items
)
SELECT sites.hostname, sites.flaggedActivity.isNew
FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) t(sites)
WHERE sites.flaggedActivity.isNew = true;
```

And it works! But what `t(sites)` means? When I try to use real table instead `dataset` of  I got error `Table 'site' not found`.

It looks very strange - like function which is invoked with `UNNEST` keyword. Can somebody explain what is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) t(sites)
```

`UNNEST()` is a set returning-function: it produces a series of rows, with one column holding the values from the original array.

This set of rows is also called a *derived table*. Here `t` is an alias for the derived table, and `site` is the name of the (only) column in this derived table.

It might be easier to understand if we add the `AS` keyword:

```
FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) AS t(sites)
```