# What does t and u mean in presto sql

Tags: sql, presto

I am reading the documentation and trying to get to the bottom of some queries.

[Here](https://www.javahelps.com/2019/11/presto-sql-types-of-joins.html) is a query with both `t` and `u`

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 1, 2) t("left"), (VALUES 3, 4) u("right");
```

Here is [another](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) using only `t`:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES 5, 2, 4, 1, 3) t(x) ORDER BY x OFFSET 2 LIMIT 2;
```

There are also these [two](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) (notice the space between the `t` and the `(`):

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores) AS t (score);
```

```
FROM (
  VALUES
    (ARRAY[2, 5], ARRAY['dog', 'cat', 'bird']),
    (ARRAY[7, 8, 9], ARRAY['cow', 'pig'])
) AS x (numbers, animals)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(numbers, animals) AS t (n, a);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62580282/what-does-tsites-means-for-presto-query) `t(sites)` is described as an alias.

```
FROM dataset, UNNEST(items) AS t(sites)
```

I have googled for hours. I hope someone with more SQL experience can point me toward useful search strings.

1. Are both u and t predefined aliases?
2. What do the aliases mean
3. Do I need the parentheses for the alias to work?
4. Do the space between the character and the parentheses have any special meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My DWH team helped me out. These are aliases combined with column names. When you know, it seems trivial.

The first example:

```
SELECT * from (VALUES 1, 2) t("x")
```

might be easier to understand written like this

```
SELECT * from (VALUES 1, 2) as t("first")
```

The `(VALUES 1, 2) as t("first")` creates a table with one column and two rows. The table has the alias `t`, and column name `first`.

```
SELECT * from (VALUES (1,3), (2, 4)) as t("first", "second")
```

Gives two rows like this

```
#    first  second
1    1      3
2    2      4
```

1. They are not predefined aliases but normal aliases
2. NA
3. You need them if the column names can not be inferred from the table
4. No